# What is swag? And where does it come from?

Tags: etymology, nouns, slang

I'd just like to know where it comes from. This is a word that I've heard all my life but it has always been a special kind of curtain. I was baffled when kids started calling each other curtains so I googled it and I just found these bullshit answers like secretly we are gay or sex with a ginger, which are obviously not what swag means.

What is swag and where does the word come from?

Comment: Im going to try to get this migrated to english.se (but bare with me, ive not done this before)

Comment: Urban Dictionary [definition 12](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Swag&defid=6751011) seems relevant.

Comment: Swag also means goods that someone has stolen. See http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/swag

Comment: @Tristan: It's also commonly used for [gifts and other "freebies"](http://www.ehow.com/how_2282558_create-swag-bags-parties.html) that are voluntarily given/available to be taken.

Comment: FF, that's a weird and surprising use of the word.

Comment: @Tristan: it's used even in the best circles: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1353/8019. But it is clearly a humorous extension of the past 'burglar's swag' meaning; I don't suppose real thieves use it any more than they wear masks and striped jerseys.

Comment: Tim, that's an interesting comment but still strange. Up until now, I had only ever heard of swag used to mean stolen goods, in the context of children's stories which included illustrations of a burglar wearing what you mentioned and carrying a sack with the word "swag" written on it. Maybe in my simple life, I'm just not very trendy.

Answer (score 7):

*Swag* as a dictionary entry traditionally has several meanings, including the one you're referencing.

*Swag* as a slang word has its roots in "swagger".

> Swagger: A very confident and typically arrogant or aggressive gait or
>   manner

It refers to a way your present yourself; having style, confidence, etc. Using the term is so popular among young people that it's generated quite a bit of backlash, especially among the internet culture. "Secretly We Are Gay" and the like are simply backronyms that serve to make fun of people.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia a "swag" is the personal possessions of someone travelling, usually on foot. Because they were rolled in a blanket, the term has come to mean a type of waterproof sleeping bag that covers the head. "Once a jolly swag-man..."